# Как убрать assets/app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, laravel-5.8

Поставил `Laravel 5.8`. Настроил `Vue`. Настроил все конфиги по [инструкции](https://github.com/starkovsky/laravel-vue-cli). Всё работает. Но все пути роутов (vue-route) начинаются с `assets/app` и дальше мой роут. Пример: `http://fl.loc/assets/app/about` 
Где и как настроить чтобы путь был такой: `http://fl.loc/about`?

Comment: В объекте конфига `base: '/'`?

Comment: @yar85 да......

Comment: Тогда путь задается либо переменной среды (вроде "BASE_URL" ее имя) для сборщика, либо в конфиге Laravel (который я вообще не знаю, к сожалению). Начать стоит именно с проверки параметров сборщика, имхо это вероятнее.